# VBA String compresssion algorithm of fixed length

Tags: string, algorithm, vba, compression

I have strings (millions of them) of 2,475 characters in size each. These strings are consisting of 0 & 1. I am converting each string to ASCII and back, so 8 initial chars become 1. This give me a much shorter length of 310 chars. But as this length is still big enough I have tried some additional compression of the already shortened string. I have used Huffman Encoding/Decoding with not so important results. I have also tried an RLE approach with better results (encoding between 205 to 212) chars over the already existing strings. But here is my problem! As I do not know the strings beforehand I am looking for a compression/decompression algorithm that produces fixed length output. Does something like that exist? I have searched also about Endless compression but without finding any solid suggestions/algorithms. Any idea will be welcomed.

Comment: Why do you need a fixed length output?

Comment: Perhaps you could try splitting the string into two strings first?

Comment: I have to store the strings in a random file that's why I need the fixed length.

Comment: @Demetres im not sure i fully understand but have you heard of fixed length strings? ie. `Dim str as String * 5` where `5` is the fixed length

Comment: @mehow My problem is not fixed length strings. If you read all the comments you will see that I am applying 2 compression algorithms on the same string, one after the other. The second algorithm is Run Length Encoding which produces variable length results. This fact adds extra complexity, as I have to keep the actual length of the compressed string. Also, the string in order to be written to a file is transferred to a bigger one. So, I was looking for a better approach but ...

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you know about the strings is that they each consist of 2475 characters and that every character is 0 or 1, then there is no fixed-length compression scheme that does better than 2475 bits (310 bytes, with 5 bits ignored). It's simple to prove that no such compression scheme can exist, since there are 2<sup>2475</sup> possible strings, and they all need to have different codes (if the compression is to be reversible). However, the shortest bit sequences which has 2<sup>2475</sup> different possible values is 2475 bits long. QED.

Of course, if some 2475-character sequences are not possible, then you can compress more by not reserving any compressed value for illegal sequences. However, in order to create an appropriate compression algorithm, you need to know what sequences are impossible, and customize the compression algorithm accordingly. So there is no general purpose algorithm.

General purpose compression algorithms do not have fixed length output because they stochastically compress certain strings to varying degrees, while other strings are compressed negatively (that is, expanded). The assumption is that all strings have some sort of internal pattern, typically a repetition pattern, and the compression can take advantage of repetitions to reduce length. To compensate, a non-repeating string will end up being expanded.

Comment: To be fair a non repeating string is unlikely, and the expansion will not be very much.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: yeah, i was oversimplifying a bit. With only a few repetitions, you get very little compression (if at all). There is still an information-theoretic limit to how much you can compress any sized subset of possible strings. But you never need to expand by much; a few bits is generally sufficient.

Comment: With my own common sense and knowledge I will agree with you. BUT what is that "Better Archiver with Recursive Functionality (BARF)" ? Also, have a look at <http://endlesscompression.com/>. There are some interesting things there.

Comment: It is said that this BARF compressor uses 257 known algorithms and can apply them repeatedly in order to achieve a 1 byte result, being also able to decompress it. This is what I tried to do, in a simplified manner and with existing tools. I also tried to download the code and run it but my antivirus says that there is problem.

Comment: With my little experiment and using only 2 algorithms (the conversion from 0,1 to ASCII and then RLE encoding) I came to a result of e.g. 210 chars, that is to say 1680 bits.

Comment: I have just completed a test over 3,100,000 strings of 310 chars.
The RLE algorithm that I use gave me results in the range 184 to 208 chars in length.

Comment: @Demetres: cool. Were the strings random or did they come out of some application? (And, by the way, did you make sure you could accurately decompress them?) In any case, that's not a "fixed-length" compression scheme, although it may be that you didn't really need one. The prevalence of compression programs amply demonstrates that most strings which show up in real-life have enough pattern in them that they can be compressed. So I'm not surprised that RLE works for some application, particularly if it's an image.

Comment: The strings are coming from an application developed by me. It has nothing to do with an image. They are actually "specifications" in order a second process to produce PostScript files. I do not say that my experiment is a fixed-length scheme, but I am supporting the idea that something like that must exist out there (BARF ?), as far as I can. I quite understand that my example is a limited, in my case, one and for a very specific use. Of course, I can use it as it is (not fixed length), giving a margin of 5-7% more in the string space that is actually needed.

Comment: Before making any adoption in new code I have made extensive test with more than a million strings. The process is absolutely reliable. I am trying to solve the problem of disk space that is needed, that's why I am struggling with the compression.